# Why are isomorphic rings also isomorphic modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $F$ be an algebraically closed field such that $char(F)$ does not divide $|G|$.

Then, Artin-Weddenburn theorem implies that there exist positive integers $n_1,...,n_k$ such that $F[G]\cong \prod_{i=1}^k Mat_{n_i}(F)$ as rings. How do I conclude that they are isomorphic as $F$-modules?

Texts I am reading say that "since they are isomorphic as rings, they are isomorphic as $F$-modules, hence $|G|=dim_F(F[G])=dim_F(\prod_{i=1}^k Mat_{n_i}(F))=\sum n_i^2$." However, to imply this, we must show that there exists an $F$-linear isomorphism which **preserves given $F$-space structures**. Since $F[G]$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n Mat_{n_i}(F)$ are isomorphic as rings, of course we can embed an $F$-space structure from one to another naturally induced by a ring isomorphism. However, dimension may differ and this does not mean that $F[G]$ and $\prod_{i=1}^k Mat_{n_i}(F)$ are isomorphic as $F$-spaces where the $F$-space structures are already given.

How do I prove this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would it be more accurate to say that your question is "If two $F$-algebras are isomorphic as rings, why are they isomorphic as $F$-vector spaces?"

Comment: @rschwieb Yes! That's right

Comment: It seems to me that these authors probably meant "since they are isomorphic as $F$-algebras they are isomorphic as $F$ vector spaces." That much is obvious, and would be the natural context.

Comment: @rschwieb Okay, so you mean I have to go the bottom of the proof and check whether those ring isomorphisms used to prove Artin-Weddenburn theorem are indeed $F$-algebra isomorphisms in this case?

Comment: Yes, I think you will find it is the case.

Comment: If $M$ is a module over $R$ then $End_R (M)$ is an $R$-module. If $M = N_1\oplus N_2$ is a sum of  $R$-modules, then there are natural $R$ module maps $End_R(M) \to End_R(N_1) \oplus End_R(N_2)$. If $N_1$ and $N_2$ are sums of copies of distinct simple $R$ modules, then the map is an isomorphism of $R$ modules. Since the A-W theorem comes from decomposing $R=F[G]$ into a sum of simple modules, you see that the matrix rings you get are actually all $R=F[G]$ modules, and the map preserves the structure. All you need to see is that the action of $F$ is the diagonal action when you identify w/ End